# Where do young wizards go before going to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Harry and Ron are old enough (11 years old) to go to Hogwarts, and Ginny cannot go because of her age. But where did she go then? Is there a wizard equivalent of elementary school or must she stay home with Molly?

Comment: They were either homeschooled and taught basic skills such as reading, writing and math, or they went to a muggle primary school. 
Kai: Where do wizarding children go to school before Hogwarts?
JK Rowling replies -> They can either go to a Muggle primary school or they are educated at home. The Weasleys were taught by Mrs. Weasley.